# Nested list and correct ng-model and ng-value in AngularJS 1.5.x

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've got a nested list/array in AngularJS as:

```
$scope.myCars = [
    name: 'Audi', types: [
        {name: 'A4', price: '150000'},
        {name: 'A6', price: '250000'},
        {name: 'A8', price: '350000'}
    ],
    name: 'BMW', types: [
        {name: 'M1', price: '250000'},
        {name: 'M3', price: '450000'}
    ]
];
```

I'm looping through the list and generate DOM by:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="car in MyCars">
        {{car.name}}:
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="type in car.types">
                {{type.name}}:
                <input ng-model="type.name" ng-value="type.price">
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

It does show everything correctly, but when I update a price in the input-field, my $watch in $scope.myCars change the type.name instead of type.price - which is wrong.

Am I doing things correctly, or?

Comment: can you add the controller code.

Comment: Typo: `ng-model="type.name"` should be `ng-model="type.price"`. You don't need to set `ng-value`.

Comment: It's not a type, it's a misunderstanding of how `ng-model` and `ng-value` work. Therefore it should not be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `ng-model="type.name"` which sets two-way data binding between the value of this input and `type.name`. If you want to have data binding with `type.price` use this instead:

```
<input ng-model="type.price">
```

Mind there's no `ng-value` here because it doesn't work with `ng-model` for the same text input element because `ng-model` overrides values from `ng-value`.

Note: `ng-value` is not meant for `<input type="text">`, it's meant for `<input type="radio">` or `option`.

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to ng-value with ng-model.
change this

```
  <input ng-model="type.name" ng-value="type.price">
```

to

```
  <input ng-model="type.price" >
```